# How to use $addToSet in Mongoose with array of ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

In MongoDB collection, I need to add unique ids only for a array field of a document. I am using findByIdAndUpdate of Mongoose. Can I pass the value as id or I need to pass the value as ObjectId() in the update body.
Should it be 1 or 2?

1.

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $addToSet: { roleIds: roleId } })
```

2. 

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $addToSet: { roleIds: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(roleId) } })
```

The schema is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roleIds: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Role",
        },
    ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats your schema , if in your schema you defined roleIds element you must use `1`

Comment: Added Schema to the question

Comment: according to use schema use 1